# Lifetime of variable in a match pattern

Tags: rust, lifetime

Trying to compile the following code:

```
#[derive(Show)]
pub enum E1 {
    A,
    B,
}
#[derive(Show)]
pub enum E2 {
    X(E1),
    Y(i32),
}

impl std::fmt::String for E1 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        std::fmt::Show::fmt(self, f)
    }
}

impl std::fmt::String for E2 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        std::fmt::Show::fmt(self, f)
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for E2 {
    fn description(&self) -> &'static str {
        match *self {
            E2::X(x) => {
                let d: &'static str = x.description();
                d
            },
            E2::Y(_) => "Unknown error",
        }
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for E1 {
    fn description(&self) -> &'static str {
        match *self {
            E1::A => "Error A",
            E1::B => "Error B",
        }
    }
}

fn main() { }
```

yields an error:

```
a.rs:17:39: 17:40 error: `x` does not live long enough
a.rs:17                 let d: &'static str = x.description();
                                              ^
note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
a.rs:15:9: 21:10 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the match at 15:8
a.rs:15         match *self {
a.rs:16             E2::X(x) => {
a.rs:17                 let d: &'static str = x.description();
a.rs:18                 d
a.rs:19             },
a.rs:20             E2::Y(_) => "Unknown error"
        ...
a.rs:15:15: 15:20 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
a.rs:15         match *self {
                      ^~~~~
a.rs:16:19: 16:20 note: attempting to move value to here
a.rs:16             E2::X(x) => {
                          ^
a.rs:16:19: 16:20 help: to prevent the move, use `ref x` or `ref mut x` to capture value by reference
a.rs:16             E2::X(x) => {
                          ^
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Changing the match pattern to `E2::X(ref x)` produces a perhaps more detailed error but leaves me just as confused:

```
a.rs:16:19: 16:24 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for pattern due to conflicting requirements
a.rs:16             E2::X(ref x) => {
                          ^~~~~
a.rs:17:39: 17:40 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the expression at 17:38...
a.rs:17                 let d: &'static str = x.description();
                                              ^
a.rs:17:39: 17:40 note: ...so that pointer is not dereferenced outside its lifetime
a.rs:17                 let d: &'static str = x.description();
                                              ^
a.rs:15:9: 21:10 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the match at 15:8...
a.rs:15         match *self {
a.rs:16             E2::X(ref x) => {
a.rs:17                 let d: &'static str = x.description();
a.rs:18                 d
a.rs:19             },
a.rs:20             E2::Y(_) => "Unknown error"
        ...
a.rs:16:19: 16:24 note: ...so that variable is valid at time of its declaration
a.rs:16             E2::X(ref x) => {
                          ^~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

The way I see it, `x` only has to live until `x.description()` returns, but the compiler seems to thing it needs to outlive the whole match block. Why? Why does it also insist on treating `x` as a reference when copying would probably be more logical?

Comment: Thanks for the expanded error messages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for `x` versus `ref x`, `x` won’t work because you have only a reference to `self` and so cannot move the `E1` value out of it—all you can do is take a reference to it.

But now the more important thing: you’ve got your definition of the `description` method incorrect, and the Rust compiler isn’t warning you about *that* but is rather making life unpleasant for you.

This is the *actual* definition of the `description` method:

```
fn description(&self) -> &str;
```

Note carefully: `&str`, not `&'static str`. The compiler should have objected to the `'static` in the signature, but alas, it did not. (This is the subject of https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21508, filed on account of this question.) Normally having specified a greater lifetime will be just fine, for it will just shrink it down to size, but in some situations it won’t do what you thought it would—specifically, it has changed `E1`’s `description` method to return a `&str` with its own lifetime, *but in the `E2` definition it is still wanting to return `&'static str`*. Of course, the `x` reference is not `'static`, so it fails to do it. Confusing, huh? Don’t worry, it’s mostly not your fault!

To fix this, remove all occurrences of `'static`, to match the trait definition. Then because `x` is inside `self` the lifetimes will line up appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. Still confused about one thing though: the `x` reference most definitely does not have long enough lifetime, but regardless the output of `x.description()` should have lifetime `'static`, no? Or does it not due to the changed lifetimes, but the compiler doesn't tell me this?

Comment: @dhardy: your `description` method should not be dealing in `&'static str`s, and the fact that it partially “fixes” it for you (being lenient and allowing `'static` rather than objecting violently) is what’s tripping you up.

Comment: Yeah, so the compiler's demoted a lifetime without telling me about it. :(

Comment: Thanks for saving me the trouble!