# "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for pattern due to conflicting requirements" in `ref mut` pattern

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
struct RefWrap<'a> {
    wrap: &'a mut Option<String>,
}

impl<'a> RefWrap<'a> {
    fn unwrap(&mut self) -> &'a mut String {
        match *self.wrap {
            Some(ref mut s) => s,
            None => panic!(),
        }
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fd85a8da40b1cdb333ff190b99fcd77a&version=stable&backtrace=0))

As far as I understand, this code is correct (the returned reference really has the lifetime `'a`. But Rust produces the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for pattern due to conflicting requirements
 --> <anon>:8:18
  |
8 |             Some(ref mut s) => s,
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

[Using immutable references](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1f7ea385c6556746d3a3305afd526a50&version=stable&backtrace=0), it works without an error.

There has been [one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089695/lifetime-of-variable-in-a-match-pattern), but I'm pretty sure it's not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the conflict is that the return value:

- Must be valid for at least the lifetime `'a`
- Must not outlive `&mut self`, which is only the lifetime of the function call.

If this were allowed, it would let you call it twice and get two `&'a mut` references to the same `String` contents:

```
let mut w = RefWrap { wrap: &mut s };
let ref1 = w.unwrap();
let ref2 = w.unwrap();  // two mutable references!
```

The reason is that the way Rust reasons about whether something is borrowed is by tying lifetimes together - but here you are explicitly saying that the return value's lifetime is unrelated to `&mut self`, which means it doesn't extend the borrow - and then you can borrow again with another call.

The solution here, to get the original reference lifetime out without risking a second `&mut` reference overlapping it, is to take `self` by value (move) so that it can't be used again.  The compiler is happy with this:

```
impl<'a> RefWrap<'a> {
    fn unwrap(self) -> &'a mut String {
        match *self.wrap {
            Some(ref mut s) => s,
            None => panic!(),
        }
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9c89cec9d2e21598ede8706553c65c84&version=nightly&backtrace=0))

Comment: "*it would let you call it twice and get two `&'a mut` references*" -> I don't think so. For example, look at [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e1fa7f12abeb7255bac4deaed23a2ce0&version=stable&backtrace=0). I used `transmute()` to make the method work, but I still can't create two mutable references. Also: I specifically want the returned reference to have the "longer" lifetime, namely `'a`.

Comment: Yes you can:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=819f30fafa65066e9f9d8c766cf17106&version=stable&backtrace=0